# Redirect to a folder in Django

Tags: python, php, django, url

Django currently has a complete system for routing urls.
But I have a very specific situation where I am using django but actually need to use urls like in classic PHP language.

For example:
The url - `localhost/reader/theeffort`  should take me to a folder called `theeffort` where I have my files `index.html`, `1.html`, `2.html`, `3.html`
and so on!

Now all these files should be accessible by `localhost/reader/theeffort/*.html` and not by Django's default url system. Is this possible to achieve that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a thing you would do with Django's URLs. If you just want to serve HTML files within a folder, they are static files; they should therefore be served by the web server itself, eg Apache. You just need to configure an alias in the Apache conf to point to the folder where the static files are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just needed some clarification1

Comment: Did you mean that this thing cannot be done through django?
or can be done by some configurations! If yes, can you explain in more details!!

Comment: The point is that Django should not be involved in serving static files anyway, although it can do so in development. This is the job of your web server itself.